# How to create method that returns ArrayList of given parameter in constructor?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, generic-programming

I've created .dat files to save a arraylist of objects using the `implements Serializable` on my object class. 
I have these two classes **Member** and **Style**, and I want to save them into an arrayList into .dat file, and I have gotten all this to work..

I have created a ReadData class which takes a fileLocation as parameter. and then has these methods

```
public boolean load() { 
public boolean save() { 
public ArrayList<Member> getMembers(){ 
public boolean add(Object [] member) {
```

The load method just takes everything from the .dat file and puts it into the arraylist
and save method just saves the arraylist. Like this: *( Just with some try catch also ;) )*

```
/* load Method */
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileLocation); 
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
this.objects = (ArrayList<Member>) in.readObject(); // <-- That Member needs to be generic also..

/* save Method */
File yourFile = new File(fileLocation); 
yourFile.createNewFile(); 
fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation, false); 
out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut); 
out.writeObject(objects);
```

And instead of creating a new class each time, I'm thinking about making a generic class that works with everything. So I could use it something like this:

```
ReadData membersFile = new ReadData("members.dat", new Member());
ReadData stylesFile = new ReadData("styles.dat", new Style());
```

So somehow my arraylist in the ReadData class will be `ArrayList<Member>` when Member object is coming from the parameter and the `ArrayList<Style>` when it's Style.

Someone that can help me to do this? or help me to achieve this in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close to getting this right. Below is the relevant code to make this generic. Unfortunately, java serialized objects are not type aware, so you will need to cast the object still.

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> ReadData(String filename, T type) {
    .....
    this.objects = (ArrayList<T>) in.readObject();
    .....
}
```

If you want to know more about generic programming, oracle has written a solid [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) that will show you the basics.

In addition to changing the method signatures for your class, you will need to make the class generic.

```
public class ReadDataMembers<T> {
    public ReadDataMember(String filename) {

    }
}
```

You don't need to pass in the type through the constructor, but you can use the following syntax

```
ReadDataMembers rdm = new ReadDataMembers<Member>("member.dat");
```

Comment: I didn't really get this to work :/ my full class is here: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/1zWfUWqy) The most important part is that I can use the getMembers (I'll rename it to getObjects) and it'll return an arraylist with the same Object type as provided in the constructor.

Comment: I've gotten it to work, but it doesn't return the right object type, I've written a little comment on the top of this file: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/3g6pUpcy)

Comment: The code in the comment at the top of the pastebin is not initializing the ReadDataMember classes with a type. use "new ReadDataMembers<Member>("member.dat");" as the constructor. You can also remove the <T> from the method signature. I thought we working with making a generic method, but not a generic class.

Comment: yes, thanks! it's working completely now! :D [Full Code](http://pastebin.com/Cic63s9g)

Comment: One more question? I'm working on the `add` method inside ReadData class.  It takes `Object[] object` as a parameter, how can I do something like this? `objects.add(new T(object));`

Comment: You want to stay away from using the Object type in a generic class. Your generic type does not have any type bounds, so it is assuming T is an object. The object type does not have a constructor, so that code probably won't compile. There are a couple different ways to handle this. The easier way is to rewrite the save method to not have Object[] as parameter instead use T[]. Secondly, you can implement a super type for the classes that you are using that has a constructor signature with Object[], and use that as the type bound.